# How do I get my view to recognize my controllers?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm writing up a comment form and can't for the life of me figure out how to get my controllers and view to talk to each other.  This is written in asp.net MVC with knockout.js

Here is the code I have:

The Javascript:

```
var postApiUrl = '/api/WallPost/', commentApiUrl = '/api/Comment/';
function getTimeAgo(varDate) {
if (varDate) {
    return $.timeago(varDate.toString().slice(-1) == 'Z' ? varDate : varDate + 'Z');
}
else {
    return '';
}
}
// Model
function Post(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.PostId = data.PostId;
self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
self.PostedBy = data.PostedBy || "";
self.PostedByName = data.PostedByName || "";
self.PostedByAvatar = data.PostedByAvatar || "";
self.PostedDate = getTimeAgo(data.PostedDate);
self.error = ko.observable();
self.PostComments = ko.observableArray();

self.newCommentMessage = ko.observable();
self.addComment = function () {
    var comment = new Comment();
    comment.PostId = self.PostId;
    comment.Message(self.newCommentMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: commentApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(comment)
    })
   .done(function (result) {
       self.PostComments.push(new Comment(result));
       self.newCommentMessage('');
   })
   .fail(function () {
       error('unable to add post');
   });


}
if (data.PostComments) {
    var mappedPosts = $.map(data.PostComments, function (item) { return new     Comment(item); });
    self.PostComments(mappedPosts);
}
self.toggleComment = function (item, event) {
    $(event.target).next().find('.publishComment').toggle();
}
}
function Comment(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.CommentId = data.CommentId;
self.PostId = data.PostId;
self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
self.CommentedBy = data.CommentedBy || "";
self.CommentedByAvatar = data.CommentedByAvatar || "";
self.CommentedByName = data.CommentedByName || "";
self.CommentedDate = getTimeAgo(data.CommentedDate);
self.error = ko.observable();

}
function viewModel() {
var self = this;
self.posts = ko.observableArray();
self.newMessage = ko.observable();
self.error = ko.observable();
self.loadPosts = function () {
    //To load existing posts
    $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            error('unable to load posts');
        });
}

self.addPost = function () {
    var post = new Post();
    post.Message(self.newMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(post)
    })
   .done(function (result) {
       self.posts.splice(0, 0, new Post(result));
       self.newMessage('');
   })
   .fail(function () {
       error('unable to add post');
   });
}
self.loadPosts();
return self;
};
//textarea autosize
ko.bindingHandlers.jqAutoresize = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm) {
    if (!$(element).hasClass('msgTextArea')) {
        $(element).css('height', '1em');
    }
    $(element).autosize();
}
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And these are my two controllers:

```
public class CommentController : ApiController
{
    private string imgFolder = "/Images/profileimages/";
    private string defaultAvatar = "user.png";
    private WallEntities db = new WallEntities();

    // POST api/Comment
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPostComment(PostComment postcomment)
    {
        postcomment.CommentedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        postcomment.CommentedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ModelState.Remove("postcomment.CommentedBy");
        ModelState.Remove("postcomment.CommentedDate");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.PostComments.Add(postcomment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var usr = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == postcomment.CommentedBy);
            var ret = new
            {
                CommentedBy = postcomment.CommentedBy,
                CommentedByName = usr.UserName,
                CommentedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : postcomment.CommentedBy + "." + postcomment.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                CommentedDate = postcomment.CommentedDate,
                CommentId = postcomment.CommentId,
                Message = postcomment.Message,
                PostId = postcomment.PostId
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ret);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = postcomment.CommentId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }



    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and

```
[Authorize]
public class WallPostController : ApiController
{
    private string imgFolder = "/Images/profileimages/";
    private string defaultAvatar = "user.png";
    private WallEntities db = new WallEntities();

    // GET api/WallPost
    public dynamic GetPosts()
    {

        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       PostedByName = post.UserProfile.UserName,
                       PostedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.UserProfile.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                       PostComments = from comment in post.PostComments.ToList()
                                      orderby comment.CommentedDate
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          CommentedBy = comment.CommentedBy,
                                          CommentedByName = comment.UserProfile.UserName,
                                          CommentedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment.UserProfile.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : comment.CommentedBy + "." + comment.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                                          CommentedDate = comment.CommentedDate,
                                          CommentId = comment.CommentId,
                                          Message = comment.Message,
                                          PostId = comment.PostId

                                      }
                   }).AsEnumerable();
        return ret;
    }


    // POST api/WallPost
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPost(Post post)
    {
        post.PostedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        post.PostedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedBy");
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedDate");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var usr = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == post.PostedBy);
            var ret = new
            {
                Message = post.Message,
                PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                PostedByName = usr.UserName,
                PostedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                PostId = post.PostId
            };
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ret);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = post.PostId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I am unsure where to link my model from.  I tried it off the ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); but that didn't seem to do much.

My View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Wall";
}

<h2>Facebook Style Wall Posting and Commenting</h2>

<div class="publishContainer">
<textarea class="msgTextArea" id="txtMessage" data-bind="value: newMessage, jqAutoresize: {}" style="height:3em;" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
<input type="button" data-url="/Wall/SavePost" value="Share" id="btnShare" data-    bind="click: addPost">
</div>
<ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
<li class="postHolder">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }"><p><a data-bind="text:     PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind="    html: Message"></span></p>
    <div class="postFooter">
        <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: PostedDate"></span>&nbsp;<a     class="linkComment" href="#" data-bind="    click: toggleComment">Comment</a>
        <div class="commentSection">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: PostComments">
                <li class="commentHolder">
                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: CommentedByAvatar }"><p><a data-    bind="text: CommentedByName"></a>: <span data-bind="    html: Message"></span></p>
                    <div class="commentFooter"> <span class="timeago" data-bind="text:     CommentedDate"></span>&nbsp;</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="display: block" class="publishComment">
                <textarea class="commentTextArea" data-bind="value: newCommentMessage, jqAutoresize: {}" placeholder="write a comment..."></textarea>
                <input type="button" value="Comment" class="btnComment" data-bind="click: addComment" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to get my view to work with my controller. like, when you do a return view(); you can attach a view to the "view".  On this I don't know how to attach my view, or that I even have to.  I'm editing to show my view

Comment: From what I can tell it needs to talk to the javascript, but I can't figure that out

Comment: you should try to understand how this works witha  simple example, this is so long I dont think you will find someone to help you

Comment: This is indeed too bloated right now. You should try to isolate the problem more before asking. One hint I can give you, is that an MVC viewmodel has NOTHING to do with Knockout/Javascript viewmodels. Communication between controller and view (ASP.NET MVC) does not really happen: the controller creates the view and returns it on request. JavaScript comes into play on the client side (the controller/view/viewmodel from ASP.NET is on the server side) so Knockout has nothing to do with the process. Knockout also uses viewmodels, but these are JavaScript viewmodels, a whole different concept.